# Multi-Thread existing C# in Script Task in SSIS

Tags: c#, multithreading, ssis, task, task-parallel-library

I have a number of SSIS packages written that query a database then use a foreach loop that contains a script task which makes REST calls to sync changes in the queried data to a destinatoion application. I'm wondering if I can use tasks in conjunction with Parallel.Invoke within the C# in the script tasks as a way to multi-thread the code?
I would prefer tasks so the .net framework can intelligently manage it's own number of threads etc.
I would rather change the C# than start copying and adding foreach loops and script tasks.
Can someone point me to the best option in this situation or give me some of the pitfalls to avoid in this situation?

[over view of the work flow.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HRVti.jpg)

Answer (score 0):

I tried using tasks but I had the wrong type of parallelism to make them effective, they ended up slowing down processing because they generated a lot of overhead and completed to quickly. I ended up letting the code remain synchronous and using a parallel for each loop instead.